# Get keys in registry

Tags: c#, foreach, registry

How do I get all registry sub keys in a registry folder such as

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\
```

using a foreach statement how would i accomplish this?

Comment: avoid calling both at the same time daniel,it was for demonstration only(i didnt know exactly what you needed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Microsoft.Win32.Registry object:

```
 private Dictionary<string, object> GetRegistrySubKeys()
 {
        var  valuesBynames   = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        const string REGISTRY_ROOT = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\";
        //Here I'm looking under LocalMachine. You can replace it with Registry.CurrentUser for current user...
        using (RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(REGISTRY_ROOT))
        {
            if (rootKey != null)
            {
                string[] valueNames = rootKey.GetValueNames();
                foreach (string currSubKey in valueNames)
                {
                    object value = rootKey.GetValue(currSubKey);
                    valuesBynames.Add(currSubKey, value);
                }
                rootKey.Close();
            }

        }
        return valuesBynames;
 }
```

Make sure to add the appropriate "using" declaration:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

Comment: With the    Dictionary<string, object> what do i put in? or how do i use your code?

Comment: You just do `var registrykeys = GetRegistrySubKeys();` then use that variable how you would [any other Dictionary<x,y>](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

if its the string of values of the keys

```
    string[] names = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\").GetSubKeyNames();
   //dont call both at same time....
    string[] values = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\").GetValueNames();

foreach (string key in values)
{
    //do your stuff...            
}
```

you need to import namespace

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
//also...
//retrieves the count of subkeys in the key.
int count = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion").SubKeyCount;
```

also check this article,might help you in your task
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

EDIT:

taken from codeproject article to read a key

```
public string Read(string KeyName)
{
    // Opening the registry key
    RegistryKey rk = baseRegistryKey ;
    // Open a subKey as read-only
    RegistryKey sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(subKey);
    // If the RegistrySubKey doesn't exist -> (null)
    if ( sk1 == null )
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        try 
        {
            // If the RegistryKey exists I get its value
            // or null is returned.
            return (string)sk1.GetValue(KeyName.ToUpper());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // AAAAAAAAAAARGH, an error!
            ShowErrorMessage(e, "Reading registry " + KeyName.ToUpper());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `OpenSubKey` twice (or three times) is a bad idea - if the registry happens to change between the two calls (rare but possible), your code will crash (or worse!) because the two arrays are differently sized and holding entirely different data.

Comment: I have edit'd the code to string[] names = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run").GetSubKeyNames();
            string[] values = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run").GetValueNames();

            foreach (string key in values)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(names+", Value: " + values);    
            } and its returning: System.String[], Value: System.String[]

Comment: ... @DanielJones - uh... do you have any experience in C#? You seem to be just kind of... doing random stuff... and don't appear to know what arrays are...

Comment: yes arrays are well....we know...:), i could have done like the other answer but this was just for demonstration purposes only,but you are right mcmonkey4eva